# Data-bound TextBox rounds values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a simple MVVM application containing a TextBox that is databound with a double property in the ViewModel. The input scope of the TextBox is set to `NumbersOnly`. The problem is that if I enter values like `4,23` the property is rounded to 4.0, so I lose the information behind the decimal separator. How can I avoid this?

The app correctly recognizes my region and sets the decimal separator to `,` as is it the case in Germany. Can this be the cause for the problem? I couldn't do much testing yet but maybe someone already ran across this behaviour (though I didn't find any help yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You bind data to Your TextBox You can also set StringFormat:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding path=property, StringFormat=N2}/> // n2 means 2 decimal places
```

Comment: When using WinRT on Windows Phone you have to use a Converter and implement the `ConvertBack` method with something like `return Math.Round(Double.Parse((String)value), 2);`

Comment: I know Converterts :) Didn't know You was asking for WinRT. Did You found Your solution ? I see You accepted my answer, but did it helped You ?

Comment: Yeah, your answer is correct for non-phone what I asked for obviously :D I forgot the `windows-phone` tag.